# unable to load the models in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am unable to load the models in file which is in **application folder**. my zend structure is like this

```
project

-- application

       --configs

       --controllers

       --models

       --views

      --cron_file.php

--libraray

--index.php
>
--htaccess
```

and in my cron file for loading models i given like this

```
    define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'.PATH_SEPARATOR .APPLICATION_PATH.'/models'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());

       $mt= new Model_Modelname;
        $mt->functionname();
```

if i execute the file like this `http://hostname/project/application/cron_file.php`
i am getting error like this

```
Warning: include_once(Model\Modelname.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 83

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Model\Modelaname.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application/../library;C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application/models;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 83

Fatal error: Class 'Model_Modelname' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\cron_file.php on line 75
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Try to load it manually instead of `Zend_Loader`.

Comment: i removed `zend_loader` and tried. Unable to load the model

Comment: But you have to place `include_once('models/yourmodel.php')` or `require_once('models/yourmodel.php')` that provide access to your models directly.

Comment: Sorry, i tried like that. unable to load it. The error `Fatal error: Class Db_Table` not found. My models `extends` the `Db_Table` properties.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably noticed, files in application folder do not fit normal autoloading standards (eg. folders are `models` and `forms`, but classes in them have names `model` and `form`). You need to add resource loader (`Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource`) with those rules to autoloader. As we want to use standard rules for Zend application then we can use bulid-in resource - `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`.

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); //application folder path
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'; //you might need to add Zend library to php path
$al = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$al->registerNamespace('Application');
$rl = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Application',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        ));
```

Now you can load classes like always in Zend - `$mt= new Application_Model_Modelname;`

Comment: i tried like this. i am getting error `Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\cron_file.php on line 76

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx`.

Comment: I hope you added Zend Framework to include path? `$path = '/path/to/zendfrmework/library';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);`

Comment: Hi @Volvox. i am unable to solve this problem. i got this error `Fatal error: Class My_Db_Table not found. My models extends the My_Db_Table properties`. Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks